# hitTest or hitTestObject to detect a collision with multiple objects in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest

I'm working on a small game and I would like to detect if the player collided with one of the boxes that are placed on the stage.
What is the best method to do this, `hitTest` or `hitTestObject`?
My code:

```
var hitTestClips:Array = [smallbox, mediumbox, bigbox] //more to come

    var fps = 60;
    var moveTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000/fps);

    moveTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onMoveTimer);
    moveTimer.start();

    function onMoveTimer(e:TimerEvent){
    player.x += Math.round(1)

    for(var player:MovieClip in hitTestClips)
    {
      if(player.hitTest(this.x, this.y, true))
      {
        trace("HIT");
      }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the enemy objects and use hitTestObject to see if a collision occurred.

```
var hasCollision:Boolean = player.hitTestObject( enemy );
```

This page describes this and various other methods: [AS3 Collision Detection](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/HitTest-AS3-for-collision-detection-Flash-Actionscript-3/68594)

Comment: Thank you! Quick question: hitTestPoint is only used for hitTests with the users mouse, right?

Comment: It could be used for anything with x,y coordinates. Using a Point is a really handy way of handling those two numbers.